# Remove rows where groups of two columns have differences

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, conditional-statements, row

Is it possible to remove rows if the values in the `Block` column occurs at least twice which has different values in the `ID` column?

My data looks like this:

| ID | Block |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |

In the above case, the value `A` in the `Block` column occurs twice, which has values 1 and 3 in the `ID` column. So the rows are removed.

The expected output should be:

| ID | Block |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | B |

I tried to use the `dropDuplicates` after the `groupBy`, but I don't know how to filter with this type of condition. It appears that I would need a `set` for the `Block` column to check with the `ID` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using window functions. The first one ([**`lag`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag)) marks the row if it is different than the previous. The second ([**`sum`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum)) marks all "Block" rows for previously marked rows. Lastly, deleting roes and the helper (`_flag`) column.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'A'),
     (1, 'C'),
     (1, 'C'),
     (3, 'A'),
     (3, 'B')],
    ['ID', 'Block'])
```

Script:

```py
w1 = W.partitionBy('Block').orderBy('ID')
w2 = W.partitionBy('Block')
grp = F.when(F.lag('ID').over(w1) != F.col('ID'), 1).otherwise(0)
df = df.withColumn('_flag', F.sum(grp).over(w2) == 0) \
    .filter('_flag').drop('_flag')

df.show()
# +---+-----+
# | ID|Block|
# +---+-----+
# |  3|    B|
# |  1|    C|
# |  1|    C|
# +---+-----+
```

Comment: @ZygD, does lag()/lead() have any impact on distributed rows? The documentation does not provide these details, nor I could reproduce it to test. ++ for this as it solved my problem; but I still have the above doubt.

Comment: @AzharKhan - As far as I know, in order to perform some calculations based on partitions, the data which belongs to a partition is moved to the same node. So, shuffling happens. So it's important to properly partition your data, I mean, without a clause `partitionBy`, the whole dataframe would be moved into one node which is not efficient. `lag`/`lead` are no different in this contxt than any other function applied over a window.

Comment: I am not sure if this is efficient but I also got the same expected output using the command below. I forgot that I needed a duplicate threshold so I ended up with this after getting some understanding with ZygD's answer. 

`duplicate_threshold=2`
`df.join(df.groupBy('Block').agg(size(collect_set('ID')).alias('_flag')).filter(col('_flag')<duplicate_threshold).drop('_flag'),on=['Block'],how='inner').select('ID','Block').sort('ID','Block').show()`

Comment: Efficiency-wise, both options look comparable. Depending on data, any of the two ways could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions. get ranks per group of blocks and through away any rows that rank higher than 1. Code below

```
(df.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('ID','Block')))#create an index to reorder after comps
 .withColumn('BlockRank', rank().over(Window.partitionBy('Block').orderBy('ID'))).orderBy('index')#Rank per Block
 .where(col('BlockRank')==1)
 .drop('index','BlockRank')
).show()

+---+-----+
| ID|Block|
+---+-----+
|  1|    A|
|  1|    C|
|  1|    C|
|  3|    B|
+---+-----+
```